# using SURF for handdetection

Tags: opencv, image-processing, surf

I'm using SURF algorithm for real time hand detection.I'll let the user put his hand in a rectangle and then use it as my object and find the hand in first frame using that object,in the next loop i'll set the detected hand as my object and so on...
But when running it shows the following error

OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (count >= 4) in cvFindHomography, file /build/buildd/opencv-2.4.8+dfsg1/modules/calib3d/src/fundam.cpp, line 235
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /build/buildd/opencv-2.4.8+dfsg1/modules/calib3d/src/fundam.cpp:235: error: (-215) count >= 4 in function cvFindHomography

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/nonfree/nonfree.hpp"

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
int main()
{

 char k;

 Mat img_object,img_scene,frame;

 VideoCapture cap(0);

 if(cap.isOpened()==0)
{
    cout<<"ERROR";
    return -1;
}
while(1)
{
    cap>>frame;
    rectangle(frame,Point(100,100),Point(300,300),(0,255,0),4,8,0);
    imshow("gig",frame);
    k=waitKey(1);
     if(k=='q')
     {
         Mat img_object1(frame,Rect(25,25,100,100));
         img_object=img_object1.clone();
         cvtColor(img_object,img_object,CV_BGR2GRAY);
        break;
    }

}


while(1)
{
    cap>>img_scene;

    cvtColor(img_scene,img_scene,CV_BGR2GRAY);

    int minHessian = 50;

    SurfFeatureDetector detector( minHessian );

    std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoints_object, keypoints_scene;

    detector.detect( img_object, keypoints_object );
    detector.detect( img_scene, keypoints_scene );


     SurfDescriptorExtractor extractor;

     Mat descriptors_object, descriptors_scene;
    extractor.compute( img_object, keypoints_object, descriptors_object );
     extractor.compute( img_scene, keypoints_scene, descriptors_scene );


     FlannBasedMatcher matcher;
     std::vector< DMatch > matches;
     matcher.match( descriptors_object, descriptors_scene, matches );

     double max_dist = 0; double min_dist = 100;


     for( int i = 0; i < descriptors_object.rows; i++ )
     {
         double dist = matches[i].distance;
         if( dist < min_dist ) min_dist = dist;
             if( dist > max_dist ) max_dist = dist;
     }

     printf("-- Max dist : %f \n", max_dist );
     printf("-- Min dist : %f \n", min_dist );


     std::vector< DMatch > good_matches;

     for( int i = 0; i < descriptors_object.rows; i++ )
     { 
        if( matches[i].distance < 3*min_dist )
           { good_matches.push_back( matches[i]); }
     }

     Mat img_matches;
     drawMatches( img_object, keypoints_object, img_scene, keypoints_scene,
             good_matches, img_matches, Scalar::all(-1), Scalar::all(-1),
             vector<char>(), DrawMatchesFlags::NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS );


     std::vector<Point2f> obj;
     std::vector<Point2f> scene;

     for( int i = 0; i < good_matches.size(); i++ )
     {

         obj.push_back( keypoints_object[ good_matches[i].queryIdx ].pt );
         scene.push_back( keypoints_scene[ good_matches[i].trainIdx ].pt );
     }

     Mat H = findHomography( obj, scene, CV_RANSAC );


     std::vector<Point2f> obj_corners(4);
     obj_corners[0] = cvPoint(0,0); obj_corners[1] = cvPoint( img_object.cols, 0 );
     obj_corners[2] = cvPoint( img_object.cols, img_object.rows ); obj_corners[3] = cvPoint( 0, img_object.rows );
     std::vector<Point2f> scene_corners(4);

     perspectiveTransform( obj_corners, scene_corners, H);


     line( img_matches, scene_corners[0] + Point2f( img_object.cols, 0), scene_corners[1] + Point2f( img_object.cols, 0), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 4 );
     line( img_matches, scene_corners[1] + Point2f( img_object.cols, 0), scene_corners[2] + Point2f( img_object.cols, 0), Scalar( 0, 255, 0), 4 );
     line( img_matches, scene_corners[2] + Point2f( img_object.cols, 0), scene_corners[3] + Point2f( img_object.cols, 0), Scalar( 0, 255, 0), 4 );
     line( img_matches, scene_corners[3] + Point2f( img_object.cols, 0), scene_corners[0] + Point2f( img_object.cols, 0), Scalar( 0, 255, 0), 4 );



    Mat nn(img_scene,Rect((scene_corners[0] ).x,(scene_corners[0] ).y,(scene_corners[2] ).x,(scene_corners[2]).y));

    imshow( "Good Matches & Object detection", img_matches );


    img_object=nn.clone();

      k=waitKey(1);
    if(k=='q')
    {
        break;
    }
} 

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not enough `good_matches`. For the function `findHomography`, the length of input vectors should be **4** at-least.

Comment: @sgarizvi Thanks for the comment . The program works fine for photos given as input.When i made it real time this error shows up,why didnt this error show up when i used photos?